# HttpInterceptor Retry request on snackbar action

Tags: angular, angular-material, snackbar

I'm using the HttpInterceptor class to centrally catch and handle unexpected errors from the server.  I've managed to succeed in accomplishing this for the most part but want to expand this a little by allowing the user to retry certain requests based on the response code.  However, I'm not sure how to go about this.  Here is what I have so far:

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // Add HTTP Auth to access the API
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('my_api_key:')
            }
        });

        // handle response
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse, caught: Observable<any>) => {
                console.log('error occurred');

                if (error.status === 401) {
                    const snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open('Error occurred', 'Retry', {
                        duration: 7000
                    });

                    snackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(() => {
                    });
                    return EMPTY;
                }
                return throwError(error.statusText);
            })
        );
    }
```

So far, it catches the error as expected and if it is a 401 error the snackbar is displayed along with retry action.  How would I issue a retry from within the snackbar action?

Answer (score 2):

You can use second parameter `caught` passed to `catchError` pipe to retry the same request.

```ts
return snackBarRef.onAction().pipe(concatMap(() => caught));
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pv1gfw-bhijrf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhttp-error-interceptor.ts)**

Comment: This a great answer, much shorter and elegant than I anticipated it to be.  Just a quick question, is it possible to retry from the  SnackBar.onAction() event instead of afterDismissed() ?  My attempts were not fruitful for this

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could reissue the exact same request with the "request()" method of HttpClient service as well:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Add HTTP Auth to access the API
    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('my_api_key:')
        }
    });

    // handle response
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse, caught: Observable<any>) => {
            console.log('error occurred');

            if (error.status === 401) {
                const snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open('Error occurred', 'Retry', {
                    duration: 7000
                });

                snackBarRef.onAction()
                 .pipe(
                   switchMap(_ => this.httpClient.request(request))
                 ).subscribe();
                return EMPTY;
            }
            return throwError(error.statusText);
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Forget my answer, I think yurzui's answer is cleaner than mine :)
rxjs"catchError" documentation saying about "caught" parameter: "... caught, which is the source observable, in case you'd like to "retry" that observable by returning it again"
Which sounds perfectly adapted the case.